# Data migration process within SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, data-migration

I have a requirement like this.

**Step 1 :** I need to retrieve the Access db's data into sql server database.I have done that by using SSMS's Import wizard tool.I have given that database name as `LegacyData`

**Step 2 :** I need to insert this Legacy data into new Sql server database called `AppData`.

**Note :** The names of the tables and the column names are different on 2 databases.

**As an e.g.** On the `LegacyData` database has a table name `Homeowner Foreclosures`.The mapping table's name of the `AppData` database is `Properties`.

Columns are like this :

`Homeowner Foreclosures` : `PLID,Deeddate,County`

`Properties` : `Id,DeedDate,CountyId`

**Note :** Here `County` is the `Name` of the `Counties` Master table and `CountyId` is the `Id` of  `Counties` table.I have to do a mapping here also.

`Counties` : `Id,Name`

Can you tell me how to do this kind of data migration process ?

Comment: First write a select statement that returns the correct data and then use that to insert the data into the new table. What is exactly the problem you have?

Comment: @JamesZ Here I have to deal with the 2 databases and also having different column names.Can you give me a simple example of it ? I mean how to do that ?

Comment: The names of the columns don't matter at all. You just have to supply them in the insert clause, something like `insert into Properties (ID...) select PLID...`

Comment: @JamesZ OK,then what are the differences should I consider when I retrieve the data from 2 databases.Can I have a sample for it also ?

Comment: This sounds really simple, so I have no idea what you're having problems with. As far as I can understand from your question, you just need to join `Homeowner Foreclosures` with `Counties`. If it's in a different database, you just have to prefix the table name with the database (+schema).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
Use AppData

Insert Properties
Select H.PLID, H.DeedDate, C.CountyID
   From LegacyData.dbo.HomeownerForclosure H
   Join LegacyData.dbo.Counties C On H.County = C.Name
```